# Custom header to pandas data frame while writing to excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have a simple data frame with a few columns

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [1, 3], [4, 6]], columns=['A', 'B'])

   A  B
0  1  2
1  1  3
2  4  6
```

what I am trying to achieve is writing to excel with a custom header which can be be multline.
So output of excel would be

```
| App Input         |                |
| --------          | -------------- |
| --------          | -------------- |
| A                 |B               |
|data               |data            |
| 1                 | 2              |
| 1                 | 3              |
| 4                 | 6              |
```

Any ideas how can I achieve this? I was thinking of mult index but I don't think it will work since its not a true multi index

Answer (score 0):

Since headers in Excel will be simple cells with string values, you can just precede the "real" values in columns with some textual values that together with the dataframe's column names are forming the multi-line header you wish to get.

For example you could use the following values to get the desired result you provided:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['', ''], ['A', 'B'], ['data', 'data'], [1, 2], [1, 3], [4, 6]], columns=['App Input', ''])
```